# PHP Merge & Sort Several Different Arrays of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, merge

I have a social networking app that uses a codeigniter REST api and one of our features is a feed of newly created content and up until now this has only consisted of user statuses, but now id like to add a variety of different content into the feed( updates,photos, user interactions, etc.)

I have functions in place that grab each type of content individually and places them in array of objects. So there is an array of object of statuses, an array of objects for photos and etc. **Each object in each of these arrays of objects has a timestamp field and I would like to merge all of these arrays of objects into a single array of objects sorted by the timestamp field all the objects share, but im not sure how to go about doing this?**

Comment: where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: do all of the objects have a timestamp field?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea how to achieve my desired effect .Regarding code if i were to post code it would only be a codeigniter controller containing several arrays of objects stored in variables which i dint think would be to helpful, but I could post 2 dummy arrays of objects if it would help you visualize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for the sorting, as long as each object has a public timestamp field

```
function compareObjTimestamps( $a, $b ) {
    return $a->timestamp - $b->timestamp;
}

usort( $objArray, 'compareObjTimestamps' );
```

For the merging, following this approach just lump all of the objects into a single array prior to the call to `usort`.

**Example**

```
<?php

class A {
    public $sortField;

    public function __construct( $sortField ) {
        $this->sortField = $sortField;
    }
}

class B {
    public $sortField;

    public function __construct( $sortField ) {
        $this->sortField = $sortField;
    }

}

function compare( $a, $b ) {
    return $a->sortField - $b->sortField;
}


$test = array(
    new A(1),
    new B(2),
    new A(3),
    new B(4),
    new B(1),
    new A(17),
    new B(10),
);

usort( $test, 'compare' );

foreach( $test as $entry ) {
    echo $entry->sortField . ': ' . get_class( $entry ) . "\n";
}
```

Multiple iterations of this script produced the following output:

```
1: B 
1: A 
2: B 
3: A 
4: B 
10: B 
17: A
```

So it looks like that whatever appears later in the input will be first in the output, although I can't find any documentation on this.  The manual simply states:

> 4.1.0     A new sort algorithm was introduced. The cmp_function doesn't keep the original order for elements comparing as equal.

Comment: This seems like a decent solution , but what would happen if the two timestamps were identical?

Comment: Check the manual entry for `usort`.  The compare function is intended to return either a negative number, 0 or a positive number indicating the relative order between the two arguments.  If they are the same the function will return 0 (indicating to usort that, for the purposes of comparison sorting, the two objects are the same)

Comment: I suppose this is a completly different question, but would you have any idea how i would go about removing duplicate items ( i would verify they are duplicates by a content_id field)

Comment: I think you should try not to have duplicates in the first place.  You wouldnt want to remove the duplicates within the compare function, but if you must have duplicates in the input you'll have to iterate over it and within the iteration iterate over the rest of the list to see if the current element is duplicated.